# How to bend a text area in android canvas?

Tags: java, android, ios

I want to implement a customview for android which is just like the UIPickerview in ios platform.
Here is what I have done:

[image]

And Below is the ios style:

[image]

I googled the relatied docs and searched stackoverflow ,but failed.

Any advice to this problem will be welcome! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the project link :https://github.com/ghuiii/PickerView

Answer (score 1):

Its Wheel control. So i would like to suggest you some links. I hope it would help you.

http://android-devblog.blogspot.in/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol-backgrounds.html

https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

after that you can customize it according to your requirments .

Comment: @ghui zhang.. if you found its helpful then accept the answer :)

Comment: Actually, the project you provide doesn't bend the text area ,It just add some gradient background ,which makes it like bended.
Thanks all the same.

Comment: @ghuiZhang yeah it behave like it is wheel's frontview. if it helped then good.